# css3 animation flickers on chrome

Tags: javascript, css

I have the following js fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/f4WHN/

when the animation ends the different frames flicker on chrome.

I tried

```
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

But this dint help out. How can i fix this issue

Comment: doesn´t fliker on iron over here.

Comment: v31 chrome and no flicker is apparent..

Comment: my chrome V 26.0.1410.64 . it flickers